# Can you play GTA 4 on PC?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-iv

One time, I went to my friend's house and saw him playing Grand Theft Auto 4 on PC. Can you do that? I tried downloading it on PC but they said on Google that Grand Theft Auto 4 can be only played on XBOX. Is that true?

Comment: Your way of Googling is odd. When I google 'GTA 4 PC' I get a hit from Wikipedia, and the rest of the result list is filled with shops selling GTA 4 for PC. Plus when I hover over your `grand-theft-auto-4` tag, I see it's available for PC. The reason you obtain downvotes is the obvious lack of research effort in your question.

Comment: `I went to my friend's house and saw him playing Grand Theft Auto 4 on PC.`  Okay, fair enough.  `Can you do that?` - what, can you do that thing that you saw?

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about GTA 4? GTA 5 is the newest game in the series and it is not on PC currently. GTA 4 has been on PC for a long time now.

Comment: yes its gta 4..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GTA IV was released on PC Dec 3rd 2008 (2nd for North America) and can be obtained as a digital download over many stores such as [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/12210/) and via Retail.